# Safari is not showing the proper height and margins of my buttons like the other browsers

Tags: html, css

I have this code https://codepen.io/saraLance/pen/LYGevXW

And for some reason Safari is showing the `play-button` without their height and not showing the margins of the `quit-button`.

How can I fix this?

```css
div {
  width: auto;
}

.screens {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.screen {
  background: red;
}

.sit-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.button-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.play-button {
  height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.quit-button {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sit-container">
  <div class="screens">
    <div class="screen">
      <div class="button-section">
        <a class="play-button">Play</a>
        <a class="quit-button">Quit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `@media (min-width: 768px) {
  width: 35%;
  margin: auto;
}` That is invalid CSS. You aren't targeting any element with that. Try fixing that first.

Comment: It does not affect the question. I delete it. Thanks for noting it!

Comment: It's also in your other question..including nesting your media query in `.strip` - unless you are using SASS/LESS/SCSS preprocessor. I'm only mentioning it, because others will.

Comment: Your HTML isn't very semantic (["div-itis" is a code-smell](https://dev.to/gdiazderadaa/divitis-and-classitis-6f2)!): Why are you using `<div class="header">` instead of just `<header>`? Similarly, why not use `<button>` instead of `<div class="button-section">`? Your `<div>`-based approach will fail accessibility tests, for example, because `<button>` has an implicit `aria-role` but your `<div>` does not.

Comment: This is an example, reality is much complicated using React and styled components. I didn't wrote the code I just have to fix some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `height` or `width` along with the value you want and `!important` tacked on. Frameworks and libraries are terrible things to be forced to work with because of the complications they impose.

There are a few ways to render elements, there are many more though

```
display: inline;/* All elements render on the same line, will wrap. */
display: inline-block;/* All elements render on same line, wrap but width can be set.*/
display: block;/*All elements render on separate lines, width can be set.*/
```

You can also instead of using `height: 200px !important` use `min-height`:

```
element {display: block; min-height: 200px;}
```

Be sure to check the browser's styling information, it will show you what CSS rules overwrite your expectation.

You may also want to take all of the HTML output and wrap it inside the following element to do a test for validity:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></div>
```

Then save that file with an `*.xhtml` file extension and open it in a Gecko browser (Waterfox, Firefox, etc) which have a much better XML parser. If there are rendering errors the whole page will break and the browser will tell you what is wrong.

In the mid-2000s there was someone who could not figure out why Safari refused to style everything the same way. After three days...*three days* he found out he was missing an attribute quote. If he had been using the XML parser instead of the HTML parser he would have discovered it in *seconds*. Bonus: HTML5 has nothing to do with parsers. My platform is built using the XML parser to serve HTML5 code.